# How do I show a string containing escape characters in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, html-escape-characters

I have a UNC file path stored in a structure

```
scope.sites = [
    {
        id: 1,
        nickname: 'Development',
        sitepath: '\\SERVERA.mydomain.com\sites\panoply\wwwroot',
        active: true
    }
];
```

I want to display the sitepath in the tooltip, as such:

```
<label style="width:100%;font-size:10px;" title="{{target.sitepath}}">
    {{target.nickname}}
</label>
```

But as backslashes are escape characters what I get is `\SERVERA.mydomain.comsitespanoplywwwroot`.

I thought I could use `{{target.sitepath.replace('\\', '\\\\')}}` or `{{target.sitepath.replace('\', '\\')}}`.

But neither of those seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you're asking for isn't possible. This would have to be fixed when scope.sites is created since it's currently providing you with malformed JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Just escape each special character with '\' so :

```
 scope.sites = [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    nickname: 'Development',
                    sitepath: '\\\\SERVERA.mydomain.com\\sites\\panoply\\wwwroot',
                    active: true
                }
```

Comment: I am getting the values from sitepath.  Not setting them